# CreateIcon from Gdiplus::Bitmap

Tags: winapi, mfc, bitmap, gdi+

Can you post example code,

to show how to `CreateIcon()` from `Gdiplus::Bitmap`?

I want to convert png, jpg, bmp to icon in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the [`Gdiplus::Bitmap::GetHICON()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Remember to free the icon with [`DestroyIcon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when you're done with it.